# Registered Tomcat server not appearing in netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, netbeans

## Netbeans tomcat issues

In Netbeans when i attempt to make a Java EE Enterprise application, The Tomcat server in which i have in setup in Netbeans doesn't appear on the list and shows the error. "No servers are registered in the IDE. To register a server, click the "Add..." button."
I got to re-add the server and it says that the server is already registered, What am i doing wrong?

I am running Java EE 6 and i have tried this with Apache Tomcat 6,7,8 and my Netbeans version is 7.2.1.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to create a JEE application with Apache Tomcat while Apache Tomcat is not a JEE server. If you have added Tomcat to your Netbeans you should be able to create Java Web applications and associate with Apache Tomcat but NOT Java EE applications until you have added JEE server like GlassFish.

To be able to add Java EE applications you need to add GlassFish server or corresponding JEE server.

Comment: I searched a lot but didn't find this anywhere else. Thanks Chris :-)